# Vue Vuetify read selected options of dynamically generated v-select elements

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

I am using Vuetify in my Vue project and populating a list of object which I am reading from the API.

I get the following JSON which I am using to generate a data:

```
users = [
    {
        "id": "1234",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "description": "Male, 25years old",
        "moods": [
            {
                "key": "1",
                "value": "Happy"
            },
            {
                "key": "2",
                "value": "Sad"
            },
            {
                "key": "3",
                "value": "Anger"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "5678",
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "description": "Female, 20 years old",
        "moods": [
            {
                "key": "1",
                "value": "Happy"
            },
            {
                "key": "2",
                "value": "Sad"
            },
            {
                "key": "3",
                "value": "Anger"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am rendering the above data as follows:

```
<template>
    <v-form>
        <v-container>
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-list
                        subheader
                        two-line
                        flat
                    >
                    <template v-for="user in users">
                        <v-list-item v-bind:key="user.id">
                            <template v-slot:default="{ active, }">
                                <v-list-item-action>
                                    <v-checkbox
                                        :input-value="active"
                                        color="primary"
                                        v-model="checkedusers"
                                        :value="user"
                                    ></v-checkbox>
                                </v-list-item-action>

                                <v-list-item-content>
                                    <v-list-item-title v-text="user.name"></v-list-item-title>
                                    <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="user.description"></v-list-item-subtitle>
                                </v-list-item-content>

                                <v-row v-if="user.moods.length > 0" align="center">
                                    <v-col
                                        class="d-flex"
                                        cols="4"
                                        sm="4"
                                    >
                                        <v-select
                                            :items="user.moods"
                                            label="Previous Condition"
                                            item-text="value"
                                            item-value="key"
                                            outlined
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </v-col>

                                    <v-col
                                        class="d-flex"
                                        cols="4"
                                        sm="4"
                                    >
                                        <v-select
                                            :items="user.moods"
                                            label="New Condition"
                                            item-text="value"
                                            item-value="key"
                                            outlined
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </v-col>
                                </v-row>
                            </template>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </template>
                    </v-list>

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <v-btn rounded color="primary" dark @click="registerConditions">Submit</v-btn>
                    </div>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-form>
</template>
```

When I click the submit button I want to read both the selected values in both previous condition select and new condition select for each user.

So ideally I want to generate something like the following:

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "description": "Male, 25years old",
    "previousConditionKey": "2",
    "newConditionKey": "2"
}
```

However all I could find online was how to read selected value of a v-select for a single dropdown. In my case the number of select elements are dynamic depending upon the user JSON list.

Any idea how this can be handled in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all add v-model="user.previousConditionKey" and v-model="user.newConditionKey" to drop downs

and watch checkedusers and remove moods:

```
watch:{
    checkedusers: function(newVal){
      this.checkedusers.forEach((el, i) => {
        delete el.moods;
      });
    }
  },
```